# Why does Solve silently give no solutions while Reduce gives some?

Tags: equation-solving

I was trying to solve this system of equations:

```
totalParts=4;
Solve[
 Join[
  {n[0] == 0, n[totalParts - 1] == 1},
  Table[2 n[i]^2 == n[i + 1]^2 - n[i - 1]^2, {i, 1, totalParts - 2}]
 ],
 Table[n[i], {i, 1, totalParts - 2}]]
```

`Solve` gave me `{}` as answer. I started to wonder where I've made a mistake, but guessed that `Reduce` may give an answer. Interestingly, the mere replacement of `Solve` with `Reduce` in the above code gives me

```
n[3] == 1 && 
 n[0] == 0 && (n[1] == -(1/Sqrt[5]) || 
   n[1] == 1/Sqrt[5]) && (n[2] == -Sqrt[(2/5)] || n[2] == Sqrt[2/5])
```

I.e. the system does have a solution, and I've checked by substitution that the solution is right.

Why didn't `Solve` give it or at least complained that it can't be solved with methods available to `Solve` as it sometimes does? I'd expect something like

```
{{n[1]->-(1/Sqrt[5]),n[2]->-Sqrt[(2/5)]},
{n[1]->-(1/Sqrt[5]),n[2]->Sqrt[(2/5)]},
{n[1]->(1/Sqrt[5]),n[2]->-Sqrt[(2/5)]},
{n[1]->(1/Sqrt[5]),n[2]->Sqrt[(2/5)]}}
```

Comment: In `Solve` you have less variables than equations. Go with `{i, 0, totalParts - 1}` to obtain the solutions.

Comment: Or use `MaxExtraConditions -> Automatic` to allow conditions on the other parameters

Comment: @corey979, @ SimonWoods these hints could go into answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Solve` wants the same number of equations and variables, so

```
totalParts = 4;
Solve[Join[{n[0] == 0, n[totalParts - 1] == 1}, 
  Table[2 n[i]^2 == n[i + 1]^2 - n[i - 1]^2, {i, 1, totalParts - 2}]],
  Table[n[i], {i, 0, totalParts - 1}]]
```

[image]

But it's a wasted effort to solve an equation of the type `n[0] == 0` and `n[3] == 1`, so

```
{n[0] = 0, n[totalParts - 1] = 1};
Solve[Table[
  2 n[i]^2 == n[i + 1]^2 - n[i - 1]^2, {i, 1, totalParts - 2}], 
 Table[n[i], {i, 1, totalParts - 2}]]
```

[image]

---

Let me also incorporate and elaborate on the [comment of Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127074/why-does-solve-silently-give-no-solutions-while-reduce-gives-some/127075#comment343741_127074) about `MaxExtraConditions`.

```
sol = Solve[
  Join[{n[0] == 0, n[totalParts - 1] == 1}, 
   Table[2 n[i]^2 == n[i + 1]^2 - n[i - 1]^2, {i, 1, 
     totalParts - 2}]], Table[n[i], {i, 1, totalParts - 2}], 
  MaxExtraConditions -> Automatic]
```

returns a conditional expression

[image]

which isn't very transparent, but one can display the solution with the assumption that the conditions are met with

```
Normal @ sol
```

[image]